# How do I show the selected value from the dropdown

Tags: php, forms, select

I have a form and here is the code for the dropdown menu. Can you help me with the code to show the selected value after submitting the form? im using php

```
 <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM professional")     or die(mysql_error()); 
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)!=0) 
    { 
    echo '<select name="professional"> 
          <option value=" " selected="selected">Choose one</option>'; 
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            { 
              echo '<option value="'.$row['prcno'].'">'.$row['prcno']."\t"."|\t".$row['name']."\t"."|\t".$row['profession'].'</option>'; 
            } 
    echo '</select>';  
    }
?>
```

Comment: do you have a `<form>` tag?

Comment: yes it is <form method="post" class="register" action="form-building-exec.php">

Comment: How come everybody here is working with SQL databases before they even have an idea how HTTP or HTML works....

Comment: Than form-building-exec.php should have the `$_POST['professional']` variable holding your selected value.

Comment: yes i have it in my exec

Answer (score 1):

You will have two Superglobal variables available to you: `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

These are arrays, and the key for each is the name of any submitted form element, whether it was POSTED or sent with GET parameters.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

To display a value would be as simple as:

```
<?php echo $_POST['form-element-name']; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are receiving the selected value in $_POST['professional'] then in your code, you should write as -

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM professional")     or die(mysql_error()); 
if (mysql_num_rows($result)!=0) 
{ 
    echo '<select name="professional"> ';
    if(isset($_POST['professional']))
        if($_POST['professional']=="")
        echo '<option value="" selected>Choose one</option>'; 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
    { 
        if(isset($_POST['professional']))
              if($_POST['professional'] == $row['prcno'])
                echo '<option value="'.$row['prcno'].'" selected>'.$row['prcno']."\t"."|\t".$row['name']."\t"."|\t".$row['profession'].'</option>'; 
        else
            echo '<option value="'.$row['prcno'].'">'.$row['prcno']."\t"."|\t".$row['name']."\t"."|\t".$row['profession'].'</option>'; 
    } 
    echo '</select>';  
}
?>
```

Comment: it says undefined variable in this line if($_POST['professional'] == $row['prcno'])

Comment: @hehehe : please check, i have done a little correction, i forgot to check if(isset($_POST['professional'])). Are you got it, let me know :)

Comment: Can you explain please, what error you are getting. So I can help :)

Comment: there is no error. its just that, it doesnt show the selected value after submitting.

Comment: before the code just check that you are getting the value in $_POST['professional'] or not.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['professional'])) echo $_POST['professional'];